# Copying file into folder via system profile

Tags: powershell, firefox, windows-7, copy-item

I'm trying to replace the prefs.js file in a Firefox profile, to change the way firefox behaves on about 5k machines.

I kill firefox, remove the file with the script

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js" -Force -Recurse
```

which works without issue.  Then I use copy-item to pull in the desired copy of prefs.js to all firefox profiles on the machine.  THIS IS THE SCRIPT I'M ASKING A QUESTION ABOUT.

```
$Target = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*"
Copy-Item "C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\prefs.js" -Destination $Target -Force -Recurse
```

When I run the script manually on my own (domain admin) account, I get access denied errors for all user profiles that AREN'T mine, but the file is successfully copied to my firefox profile.  This seems normal, as it's only running with normal permissions.  Here's an excerpt of the log from that execution:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\PrefsJSReplace.ps1:2 char:11
+ $Target = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Fir ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\<removed>\AppData:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\PrefsJSReplace.ps1:2 char:11
+ $Target = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Fir ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\<removed>\AppData:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

However, when I send out the script with our deployment solution (like SCCM, etc), I receive the following error:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Copy-Item): "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified method is not supported."
Copy-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified 
method is not supported.
At C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\PrefsJSReplace.ps1:3 char:61
+ ... tem "C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\prefs.js" -Destination $Target -Force  ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 Copy-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'
required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\PrefsJSReplace.ps1:3 char:61
+ ... tem "C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\prefs.js" -Destination $Target -Force  ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

When I first noticed this, I thought the script needed something like a 'foreach' to address each entry that $Target would pull (running the script for ALL firefox profiles), instead of -recurse.

If that were the case, then it also shouldn't work at all when I run it manually, but when I do it goes through each profile, gives me access denied for the locations I can't edit without elevated permissions, works for my profile, and finishes without the convert error.

Can anyone help me understand why my Copy-Item can't resolve the destination $Target when ran by the system profile?

Comment: `$Target` is a collection of directory and file objects `copy-item` wants a specific destination. You would need a loop there. Running elevated with an appropriate account _should_ address the other issue. `-Recurse` has context for the source... not destination

Comment: Well, the 'other issue' is that it doesn't encounter that problem when ran locally.  I can post in the log, but it just runs through each of the user directories on the machine without issue.

Comment: When run locally does it find more than one `$target`?

Comment: It does.  That's the weird thing.  I added some of that log to my original post, it's the 3rd block of code there.  I didn't post the entire thing, but it just runs through that same error for each profile present on the machine.  I've replaced my script with one from the answer below, which appears to be working.  

Still curious about why it works when I run it locally though.

Comment: Figured it out.  $Target was finding multiple locations, but because it didn't have access to any of them besides mine, $Target effectively equalled <my profile>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a array of objects using $Targets

```
$Target = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*"
```

You are then not piping the output but instead just putting the array in a new command.
Try this

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*" -Directory | foreach-object{Copy-Item "C:\DTS\BMC\ReplacePrefsjs\prefs.js" -Destination $_ -Force -Recurse}
```

Comment: This is working on my test boxes.  Still not sure why my bad script would run through each profile when ran locally, but I can figure that out when the company isn't having an internet outage.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably becuase on your computer you are only getting 1 object which wouldn't make it a array of objects but just a singular one.

Comment: I could see that, but when I ran locally I got errors for each user profile, saying I didn't have access to drop a file in them.  So in that case it appeared to be seeing and running the script on each profile. 

I've added some of that log to my original post, it's the 3rd block of code there.  It's not the whole thing, but it just runs through that same error for each profile present on the machine.

Comment: Ok you're right.  Just took another look.  Since the 'Get-ChildItem' is where I'm getting the errors, it looks like it's trying to make the array but only has permissions to see my profile, so that's all it gets.  Then, the 1 profile has no problem being piped into the Copy-Item command.

Thanks again.